# How to manually score multinomial regression data in SAS?

Tags: sas, logistic-regression, multinomial

suppose I ran a multinomial logistic regression in SAS..there are 3 levels of the dependant variable... Suppose I have a model with estimates for some significant variables..

How do I manually score this in SAS?

Is there an easy way of doing this?

In a linear regression, If I know var1 has -0.925 as estimate and var2 has 1.23 as estimate and the error is -.0543 and Intercept is 2.543, then equation is
Ypred= 2.543+(-0.925)*var1+(1.23)*var2; This way I can score a new dataset which has var1 and var2 and create the YPred.. I know I can use proc score and input parameter estimates from the proc logistic , but how do I define the model equation manually?

Please help me out here...

Comment: https://communities.sas.com/message/155316#155316

Comment: Many thanks Reese for your answer.